# Selected RadioButton on ButtonGroup doesn't show into TextArea in Java

Tags: netbeans, jradiobutton, buttongroup

I'm a student and right now I have a project for my college.
this is short of my code.

```
private void buttonProccesActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                        

    String gender = String.valueOf(buttongroupGender.getSelection());
    //the problem is right over top of this comment

    String date = String.valueOf(comboboxDate.getSelectedItem());
    String month = String.valueOf(comboboxMonth.getSelectedItem());
    String year = String.valueOf(comboboxYear.getSelectedItem());

    textareaWrite.setText("");
    textareaWrite.append("\nName : " + textfieldName.getText());
    textareaWrite.append("\n" + gender);
    textareaWrite.append("\nBirth : " + date);
    textareaWrite.append(" - " + month);
    textareaWrite.append(" - " + year);
    textareaWrite.append("\nBirth place : " + textfieldBirthPlace.getText());  

}
```

Everything, every code is working perfectly except the button group.

> String gender = String.valueOf(buttongroupGender.getSelection());

I can't get the value of radio button that is selected in button group that has the value of Boy and Girl.
Is there any solution for this ?

Comment: Can you provide the codes for your button group creation??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve your problem you have to add `setActionCommand` to all the `JRadioButton` during their creation.

**Example:**

I assume that you have already created two `JRadioButton` namely `boy` and `girl` in the constructor part. There you also have to include two more lines each after the `JRadioButton` as below:

```
boy = new JRadioButton("Boy");
java.setActionCommand("Boy");
girl = new JRadioButton("Girl");
c.setActionCommand("Girl");
```

Now, in your `buttonProccesActionPerformed()` method (the code which you have provided), do the following edit:

```
String gender = buttongroupGender.getSelection().getActionCommand();
```